# How to use own CMS login as Wordpress login

Tags: wordpress, cookies, authentication, content-management-system, share

I manage a own CMS with own Login, but there is also a wordpress Instalation as sub-Website, as a part of the whole System.

I would like to ask if there is any way to use the own CMS Login for the Wordpress installation?

Thanks in advice

best regards
Bukso

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For that above requirement, you need matching username/password with WP site.

When users are trying to register into your site use `wp_create_user( $username, $password, $email );` and when users are logging into your site you can use following code

```
$creds = array(
    'user_login'    => 'example',
    'user_password' => 'plaintextpw',
    'remember'      => true
);

$user = wp_signon( $creds, false );
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the fast answer, I will test this! :)

Comment: I would use wp_create_user( $username, $password, $email ); for new user, but what to do for the users that are already registered in the DB, with crypted passwords?

Comment: Create user will take care of that... from WP admin you can't know passwords they are already salted... but you can reset them and match with your site and send them by mail...